# Are country fixed effect necessary?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, panel-data

I have a model where I'm trying to estimate the effect of FDIs on a technological variables across countries.

Y= X1, X2, ...., u

Y is my technological variable
X1 FDI 
X2 exp
.. other control variables.

As I am looking at one specific sector that has regional much more than global patterns, I was wondering if country fixed effects are fundamental to have a proper model or if it is enough to control for geographical regions (e.g. Europe, NAFTA, Asia, dummy for China), so not to have country dummies but regional areas dummies.

Also any examples in the literature?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Carla. What is your unit of analysis? Are you observing the technological outputs of *countries* across years, quarters, months, etc.? Such is necessary for a fixed effects analysis. Or, maybe you are looking at the outputs of *businesses* within countries. It is important for other readers of your question to know how your data is clustered.

Comment: @Tom Hi Tom. I have number of technologies (my dependent variables) for 34 countries for 11 years.

Comment: Does one sector have a large influence across multiple countries? Do you have data on countries *not* receiving any investments? Consider refining your question slightly so others can home in on your exact question.